# Webpack 5 favicon, i have 404 error in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to connect favicon to my project and i just have error 404 (cannot get access) but after F5 this error disapear and  favicon still dont show,if you know another way or how to corect my way help me

it is my way to connect favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" />
```

and my config

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const isProd = argv.mode === 'production';
  const config = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      clean: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.jsx?$/,
          use: ['babel-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /.s?css$/,
          use: [isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|ico)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'images/[name][ext]',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
  };

  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
      }),
    );
  }

  return config;
};
```

Comment: Why are you adding the link to the favicon, when you already reference it via `HTMLWebpackPlugin`? Why do you use different paths? Which is the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the **CopyWebpackPlugin** https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ .
Basically, the CopyWebpackPlugin just copies a file from your source to your output directory.

Why you'd want to use CopyWebpackPlugin:

1. Webpack will not rename the file to something else
2. Webpack will not inline the file
3. You don't need to figure out a way to tell Webpack that the file is needed in the output

Add the following section to your `plugins` array in your webpack config file:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
// later, in plugins array, add:
plugins: [
    // .. other plugins ...
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: "src/images/favicon.ico", to: "images/favicon.ico" },
            ],
        }),
]
```

You will need to keep your `<link>` tag in the HTML and may have to remove that `favicon` property in the HtmlWebpackPlugin config.